# What is createEmbeddedView() context parameter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to know what purpose the `context` parameter serves in `createEmbeddedView()` method in Angular. The online angular docs do not provide this information.

For example I was reading this code where the author has made an iterator structural directive.

```
    import {
    Directive, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, Input, SimpleChange
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[paForOf]"
})

export class PaIteratorDirective {
    constructor(private container: ViewContainerRef, private template: TemplateRef<Object>) {
    }

    @Input("paForOf") dataSource: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.container.clear();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource.length; i++) {
            this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, new PaIteratorContext(this.dataSource[i]));
        }
    }
}

class PaIteratorContext {
    constructor(public $implicit: any) { }
}
```

This is shown on the checkbox checked event on the template like this:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showTable" />Show Table</label>
</div>
<table *paIf="showTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <template [paForOf]="getProducts()" let-item>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</table>
```

I want to understand this code:

```
this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, new PaIteratorContext(this.dataSource[i]));
```

Why i need to create an object of PaIteratorContext() class? why i can't just do this:

```
this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, this.dataSource[i]);
```

Please help ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you define a template you can have input parameters specified through `let-paramname`:

```
<template [paForOf]="getProducts()" let-item='item'>
     <span>{{item.name}}</span>
</template>
```

The context object is what allows you to pass those parameters to the template when creating it.

```
this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {item: {name: 'John'}}`
```

> Why i need to create an object of PaIteratorContext() class? why i
>   can't just do this:

You don't have to create an instance of the `PaIteratorContext`, you just have to pass an object with the `name` property in that particular case. So the following will work as well:

```
this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, { $implicit: this.dataSource[i] });
```

If the input property is specified like this `let-item` without second part `=something`, the embedded view treats it as `let-item=$implicit` so you have to pass a context object with `$implicit` property.

Comment: OK, why i have to use new PaIteratorContext() and then pass them on it? what's the purpose of this class - PaIteratorContext() here?

Comment: @yogihosting, you don't have to create an instance of the class, you just have to pass an object with properties relevant to the ones specified with `let-*`

Comment: OK, if i pass them as object like this - this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, this.dataSource[i]); then why the code does not work?

Comment: Thank you $implicit does the work here - this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, { $implicit: this.dataSource[i] }); . I understood that $implicit is creating the appropriate property for the dataSource on runtime.

Comment: Thank you for excellent details, there was absolutely no information on this on the whole net until your answer came.

Comment: @yogihosting, you're welcome. Check out my blog, there's a lot of information there not available anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `{item: 'someValue'}` then the stamped template can access the value using

```
<template let-foo="item"> 
  <div>{{foo}}</div>
</template>
```

or if you pass  `{$implicit: 'someValue'}`

```
<template let-foo> 
  <div>{{foo}}</div>
</template>
```